# How can I get a particular output file by using shell script and awk?

Tags: bash, shell

I have an input file: 
add.txt:

```
\\91191191111,us-west-2
293jsa3jj3nj3
4535jn4545jnj
2324jnjnnjk54
5jnj54jnk3533
\\00012985868,us-west-2
2232sddmakma
231900aasa00
324km2kmk433
\\9292011323,us-west-1
\\9203290324,us-west-2
cfdcfdc23213
```

What I'm looking to achieve is:

```
\\91191191111,us-west-2,293jsa3jj3nj3
\\91191191111,us-west-2,4535jn4545jnj
\\91191191111,us-west-2,2324jnjnnjk54
\\91191191111,us-west-2,5jnj54jnk3533
\\00012985868,us-west-2,2232sddmakma
..
..
.
```

Please let me know how can I do that?

Comment: \91191191111,us-west-2 
293jsa3jj3nj3 
4535jn4545jnj 
2324jnjnnjk54 
5jnj54jnk3533 
\00012985868,us-west-2 
2232sddmakma 
231900aasa00 
324km2kmk433 
\9292011323,us-west-1 
\9203290324,us-west-2 
cfdcfdc23213

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `awk`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick, rough start for you -

```
while read line
do case "$line" in
   *,*) key="$line";;
     *) echo "\\$key,$line";;
   esac
done < add.txt
```

which produces

```
\\91191191111,us-west-2,293jsa3jj3nj3
\\91191191111,us-west-2,4535jn4545jnj
\\91191191111,us-west-2,2324jnjnnjk54
\\91191191111,us-west-2,5jnj54jnk3533
\\00012985868,us-west-2,2232sddmakma
\\00012985868,us-west-2,231900aasa00
\\00012985868,us-west-2,324km2kmk433
\\9203290324,us-west-2,cfdcfdc23213
```

It ignores `\\9292011323,us-west-1` as it has no following data lines.

An `awk` with similar logic will be faster on a large data file.

If you want to print lines even if they have no data sections, add and check more flags.